# How to change the properties of a Blaze Template inside a React Component

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-accounts, meteor-react

I'm using the Accounts UI meteor package in my React + Meteor project and want to render the `loginButtons` template with the property `align="right"`. In Blaze the code would just be `{{> loginButtons align="right"}}`, but I'm at at a loss with how to add this property in React.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Blaze } from 'meteor/blaze';

export default class AccountsUIContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
  this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons, // How do I give loginButtons `align="right`?
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Blaze.remove(this.view);
  }

  render() {
    return <span ref="container" />;
  }
}
```

I think `Blaze.renderWithData()` may be part of the solution, but my tests with this method haven't worked so far. I also think people have created solutions to using Blaze templates in React before, but I'm not sure these alternate solutions would be the "right" way to solve this problem in Meteor 1.4.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was right inside the documentation. First `meteor add gadicc:blaze-react-component`, then in the component

```
import React from 'react';
import Blaze from 'meteor/gadicc:blaze-react-component';

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Blaze template="loginButtons" align="right" />
  </div>
);
```